# Python sklearn text prediction always return the same result

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was initially using MultinomialNB and the code works just fine in predicting new text. But when I changed it to SVC it always return array (1) which means 'not technology' even though I was predicting 'computers are cool'. After checking around apparently it returns 'politics' every single time.
There is no problem with MultinomialNB using the same code.
What did I do wrong?

note the training data is a tab separated file with news title and category, something like.

```
Title                                   Category
The new President of United States      politics
```

Here is the code:

```
path="c:/newstrainingutf8.txt"
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics

news=pd.read_table(path, header=0, names=['category', 'title'], encoding='utf-8')

news['category_num']=news.category.map({'business':1,'entertainment':1,'health':1,'politics':1,'science':1, 'technology':0, 'world':1})
X=news.title
y=news.category_num
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,random_state=1)
vect=CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_train_dtm=vect.fit_transform(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_test_dtm=vect.transform(X_test.values.astype('U'))
svm = svm.SVC()
svm.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
y_pred_class=svm.predict(X_test_dtm)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class)

svm.predict(vect.transform(['computers are cool']))

newinput="f:/newinput.txt"
newoutput="f:/newoutput.txt"
input=pd.read_table(newinput, header=0, names=['cat','title','link'], encoding='utf-8')
input.cat=svm.predict(vect.transform(input.title))
input.to_csv(newoutput, sep='\t', header=None, index=None, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is simply use LinearSVC instead, since SVC apparently only compare one vs one category, while LinearSVC compare one vs the rest.

Comment: Did not understand what you said. SVM has a `decision_function_shape` with default value `"ovr"` - one vs rest.

Comment: To be honest I'm still a beginner and this is the simplest way to do it after reading the documentation. Didn't know there is another option. I'll look for it, thank you.
edit: I read the docs and it said it defaults "ovr" already, but it didn't work for some reason.